# NTLoginModule: Where does it retrieve user information?

Tags: java, single-sign-on, jaas

I want the user to be able to Single-Sign-On, i.e. once logged on as *Windows User*, all services offered by my application should be accessible without further authentication.

In order to authenticate the user I'm using `JAAS` (Java Authentication and Authorization Services), which is integrated in Java.

The Java API ships also with a several JAAS `LoginModule`s. One of them is called `NTLoginModule`, which retrieves user information about the currently logged on Windows User.

1. Where does NTLoginModule retrieve
   its information from?
2. Can I use the
   information returned by NTLoginModule in order to authenticate - in a safe manner -
   the current user?
3. Are there any security issues I have to know about?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment to rds' answer: "I learned that NTLoginModule is quite insecure. I was able to fake the returned username by replacing the NTUserPrincipal.class file in the rt.jar package and so I was able to return a bogus user name. So it's not suitable for any kind of authentication."

Additionally, by doing some researches I found out that NTLoginModule retrieves it's information from nt.dll, which is part of the Java native libraries for Windows. nt.dll uses advapi32.dll in order to retrieve the current's user information.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot help with JAAS, last tyime I did SSO with NTML, it was based on jCIFS.

However, I'm replying on your third point: There are security issues with NTLM

- [NTLM is quite weak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM#Vulnerabilities) (even v2), and you *should* lock accounts after a given number of login failures (to avoid brute force attack).
- NTLM cannot work other a firewall.
- NTLM token cannot be trusted by a third party, leading to the [double-hop problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx). Your application cannot take the identity of the logged in user to call another NTLM-protected server (like a web service; a RSS feed; or any web resource).
- NTLM is not supported by all browsers. Internet Explorer and Chrome works natively ; Firefox needs to edit a configuration for each targeted site ; Opera, Konqueror don't support NTLM at all.

Comment: NTLM is not the same as NTLoginModule, I think. However, I learned that NTLoginModule is quite insecure. I was able to fake the returned username by replacing the NTUserPrincipal.class file in the rt.jar package and so I was able to return a bogus user name. So it's not suitable for any kind of authentication.

Comment: NTLMv2 is not that weak. All of the references to cracking NTLM refer to the very very old DES based v1 or by tricking someone into connecting to a service they control. Domain Controller Security Policy controls locking accounts on login failures not the protocol. The weakest link is probably if someone sniffed out the hashes during an auth but trying to brute force an 8 byte challenge and MD4 key is not a trivial exercise. Maybe if your the NSA perhaps. Kerberos algos hash many times in a loop so that significantly more computing power is required to compute one hash.